# Activity excludeFromRecents not working on Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm trying to finish an activity and not have it on the recents. The following code seems to work on KitKat but not on lolipop, as the activity always shows on the recents.

```
intentInvite = new Intent( context, OnInviteActivity.class );
intentInvite.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intentInvite.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intentInvite = createInviteIntent( intentCloud, intentInvite );
context.startActivity( intentInvite );
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".OnInviteActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:excludeFromRecents="true"
          android:noHistory="true"
```

Answer (score 6):

Try adding an unique taskAffinity:

```
<activity android:name=".OnInviteActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:taskAffinity=".OnInviteActivity"
          android:excludeFromRecents="true"
          android:noHistory="true"
```

Answer (score 5):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27633500/1269737 - that's well known Android Issue.

This can be done programmatically

> ```
> ActivityManager am =(ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
> if(am != null) {
>     List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = am.getAppTasks();
>     if (tasks != null && tasks.size() > 0) {
>         tasks.get(0).setExcludeFromRecents(true);
>     }
> }
> ```

If Task Root Activity is excluded from recent, all activities in this task will be excluded too.

Comment: Based on my combination of attributes under the `<activity/>` node in the manifest file, this solution was the only one which worked.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue into Android 5.0, since L preview. Seems Google is working on it.

Below are open issues for the same

1. [android:excludeFromRecents not works](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1662&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&start=600)
2. [excludeFromRecents="true" not working in Android L](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78862)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with android `Jelly Bean` and I had this in my manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:excludeFromRecents="true"
          android:noHistory="true" />
```

I removed `android:noHistory="true"` and it worked, the recent apps stopped showing my activity. Looks like the `noHistory` and `execludeFromRecents` are not compatible together for some reason.